# Pure Javascript Front-end connecting to a BaaS (Can it be done?)

Tags: javascript, security, web-applications, obfuscation, frontend

I am quite determined to do a pure Javascript front-end (Using JS and GWT) connecting to a back-end using Ajax on a separate server. My concern is with security.

**What could be a solution for a Pure Front-end application?**

For example, a user-generated content site:

- When we look at it at a perspective of an app that to gain access to it it needs to ask user to login, so here Oauth can take over. The app is authenticated properly and access to any content is based on the authorization given.
- The problem is here: For an application that can allow anonymous users to view user generated content without logging in thus there is no chance for Oauth to take place.

**Connecting to a BaaS:**

- There will be no Java middleware to store application key for Baas access (e.g. Kinvey etc.)
- Even if obfuscated the application key can easily be snooped from the HTTP requests.

What could be a solution for a Pure Javascript front-end to connect to a BaaS or independent backend? In terms of securing application keys? Where Baas or independent backend can know if it is to serve data to the requesting client (even its a web app) since its not from the same domain.

Comment: Really not clear what your perceived problems are and final question is far too broad.

Comment: I have updated the final question

Comment: Must the user-generated content be accessed by other authenticated-users? Or must it only be available to the author?

Comment: @Alex Yes, all content stored by some type, like a "Post" for example should be visible to the public eye, but not all fields of the "Post" stored are returned for sure. So data is not an issue. Public gets just a subset of what is stored. The application key is the problem, where should it be stored?

Comment: Does the BaaS API require the key to be send without any processing, or must the key be used to sign/authenticate data? I understand that you are referring to any given BaaS, but its an important assumption to know about.